# How can I make my code produce pseudo random integers

Tags: java, random

So for one option within my program I am trying to create a pseudo random number generator. I can't quite figure out how to make my code produce the same random number when the same seed is entered by the user. I know I need to ask the user to enter the seed but I'm not sure what would be the appropriate code to use.

```
else if ( choice == 2){

    input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR\nTo generate a random number, I need to create a random number generator.\nTo create a random number generator that can be predicted (graded).\nI need to get the seed of the generator.\nPlease enter an integer value in Java's int range to be used as my seed.\nJava's int range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, inclusive:");


    Random rng = new Random();
    input.nextLine();

    int incl = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter min value:");

    input.nextLine();
    int min = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter max value:");

    input.nextLine();
    int max = input.nextInt();

    int randNum = rng.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    System.out.println("Random value is:" + randNum);
}
```

Comment: Next time, try checking the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) of the classes you're using before asking a question.  Just searching the Random doc for "seed" would turn up both the Random constructor taking an initial seed and the `setSeed` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your println, it looks like you're using Java.

Get the seed from the user and pass it into Random(seed): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)

```
int incl = input.nextInt();
Random rng = new Random(incl);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to set the seed of a random number generator,

I would suggest you use this function:

```
cin >> Value;

srand(Value);
```

be sure to include the apropriate header:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

(This is for C++, next time please specify the code you are using)

Comment: This question is about Java, but your answer is in C++

Comment: Sorry, the tag was not added when I answered this question while surfing C++ questions.

Comment: System.out.println can be only Java - it is immediately obvious

Comment: Even if you've never worked with Java, it should have been obvious to you that it wasn't C++, so giving an answer in a language that wasn't being used is not helpful.